# Ordinary kriging with three dimensions in R

Tags: r, kriging

I want to interpolate temperature for a surface defined by three coordinates: longitude, latitude and altitude. I know one option is to use universal kriging on two dimensions and use altitude as a regressor. ¿is there a way to perform ordinary kriging on three dimensions with the gstat package in R? ¿what option (3d ordinary kriging or 2d universal kriging) is likely to produce more accurate interpolation results?

Comment: You don't want to do this interpolation with 3D kriging: not only is it inappropriate for such data (because the surface is confined to a two dimensional manifold), it would be impossible to identify a variogram model (because you do not have suitable point-pairs aligned in near-vertical directions).

Comment: So you recommend the universal-kriging option with altitude as a regressor?

Comment: It would be negligent of me to recommend anything on the basis of so little information. It is clear, though, that this is not a 3D problem.